# Error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I am using Visual Studio 2015. This error recently showed up and I have tried many different ways to solve it that have been answered on internet.
This is my Development Server Setting: [image: Dev Server Setting]

And this is what I see on my console when I visit the SSL URL:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
    material-1.1.4.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    reveal.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    leaflet.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    leaflet.extra-markers.min.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    styles.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    modernizr-2.8.3.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    dropzone.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    angular-1.5.11.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    mask.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    angular-ui-router.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    angular-animate-1.5.11.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    angular-aria-1.5.11.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    angular-messages.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    angular-material-1.1.4.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    ng-dropzone.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    classList.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    head.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    html5shiv.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    reveal.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    Leaflet.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    mapbox.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    common.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    app.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    Navigation.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    MobileNavigation.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    FAQ.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    About.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    Login.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    ForgetPassword.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    Register.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    Transfer.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    TransferReceive.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    FileAClaim.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    RepairLocator.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    Home.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    MyAccount.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    Verification.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    jquery-3.1.1.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    bootstrap.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    ico_close_grey@2x.png Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    respond.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    bounce-logo-red.svg Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    bounce-logo-white.svg Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    dropzone.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    map_pin_static@2x.png Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    angular-1.5.11.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    circle_plus-01.png Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    mask.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    angular-ui-router.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    angular-animate-1.5.11.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    angular-aria-1.5.11.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    angular-messages.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    angular-material-1.1.4.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    ng-dropzone.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    classList.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    repairlocator:381 GET https://localhost:44331/lib/js/head.min.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    repairlocator:382 GET https://localhost:44331/lib/js/html5shiv.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    repairlocator:383 GET https://localhost:44331/js/reveal.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    repairlocator:384 GET https://localhost:44331/js/Leaflet.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    repairlocator:385 GET https://localhost:44331/js/mapbox.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    repairlocator:386 GET https://localhost:44331/Scripts/w3/common.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    repairlocator:387 GET https://localhost:44331/Scripts/w3/app.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    repairlocator:388 GET https://localhost:44331/Scripts/w3/controllers/Navigation.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    repairlocator:389 GET https://localhost:44331/Scripts/w3/controllers/MobileNavigation.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    repairlocator:390 GET https://localhost:44331/Scripts/w3/controllers/FAQ.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    repairlocator:391 GET https://localhost:44331/Scripts/w3/controllers/About.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    repairlocator:392 GET https://localhost:44331/Scripts/w3/controllers/Login.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    repairlocator:393 GET https://localhost:44331/Scripts/w3/controllers/ForgetPassword.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    repairlocator:394 GET https://localhost:44331/Scripts/w3/controllers/Register.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    repairlocator:395 GET https://localhost:44331/Scripts/w3/controllers/Transfer.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    repairlocator:396 GET https://localhost:44331/Scripts/w3/controllers/TransferReceive.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    repairlocator:397 GET https://localhost:44331/Scripts/w3/controllers/FileAClaim.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    repairlocator:398 GET https://localhost:44331/Scripts/w3/controllers/RepairLocator.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    repairlocator:399 GET https://localhost:44331/Scripts/w3/controllers/Home.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    repairlocator:400 GET https://localhost:44331/Scripts/w3/controllers/MyAccount.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    repairlocator:401 GET https://localhost:44331/Scripts/w3/controllers/Verification.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    repairlocator:1 Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4='. The resource has been blocked.
    util.js:68 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
        at util.js:68
        at util.js:10
        at bootstrap.min.js:6
        at bootstrap.min.js:6
    (anonymous) @ util.js:68
    (anonymous) @ util.js:10
    (anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
    (anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
    circle_minus-01.png Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    :44331/logo.png:1 GET https://localhost:44331/logo.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I have absolutely no clue whats causing this. Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you run SSL Diag to check if HTTPS is misconfigured? https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, the port number in my Web.config was wrongly specified. Thanks :)